# Inner json property remove

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "CIT": "Branch",
    "travel": {
        "arrival": {
            "time": "2021-02-06T04:44:30Z"
        },
        "departure": {
            "time": "2021-02-06T09:08:11Z"
        },
        "homearrival": {
            "time": "2021-02-06T11:26:25Z"
        },
        "homedeparture": {
            "time": "2021-02-06T04:44:29Z"
        }
    },
    "cusname": "Mr. Senesh",
    "appstatus": "Complete",
    "cuscontact": "0252223597",
    "serviceend": "2021-02-06T09:08:05Z",
    "servicestart": "2021-02-06T06:49:47Z"
}
```

I want to remove homearrival tag. I had parse it as JObject using newtonsoftjson (eg. JObject calldetail = JObject.Parse(Model.Calldetail); )

calldetail .Property("homearrival ")?.Remove(); didn't work.

Comment: Please format your question so that it's easier to read. Please also provide your effort so far.

Comment: What happens when you Parse it into object definition which does not have HomeArrival property. Removes/Skips the tage isnt it..!!

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I'm not parsing it to object definition its  dynamic JSON. I'm parsing it to JObject using Newtonsoft lib.

Comment: @John I have formatted plz help

Comment: "homearrival" isn't a property of `calldetail`. "travel" is a property of `calldetail`, and "homearrival" is a property of "travel".

Comment: @John I want to remove homearrival  entire tag how can I do that without affecting other tags ?

Comment: What's stopping you? You seem to know how to do it already, you were just trying to access the property in the wrong place.

Comment: @John I'm confused with the syntax. can we directly remove it from calldetail  ?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, no. It isn't a direct descendent of `calldetail`. I believe you can write some kind of query that finds it from `calldetail` but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: My Answer JObject m = JObject.Parse(calldetail["travel"].ToString());
 m.Property("homedeparture")?.Remove();

  calldetail["travel"] = m;

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are on the right track. However, the "homearrival" property is not a property of the "calldetail" parent object. It is a property of the "travel" sub-object.

In order to remove the "homearrival" property, you will need to call the "Remove()" method on the "travel" sub-object. For example, I believe the following code snippet should solve the problem:

```
JObject calldetail = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JObject travel = (JObject)calldetail.Property("travel").Value;
travel.Property("homearrival").Remove();
```

Please note that there may be a more efficient way to do this. The above code snippet is just meant to be a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
JObject m = JObject.Parse(calldetail["travel"].ToString()); m.Property("homedeparture")?.Remove(); 
calldetail["travel"] = m;
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.